# convert NSString into NSAttributedString without alloc init

Tags: ios, nsattributedstring

I want to convert `NSString` into `NSAttributedString`.
But i always have to do

```
 NSAttributedString *useDict1=[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"String"];
```

Is there any other way such that i don't have to allocate the `Dictionary` every time, but just give the string?

Comment: This is pre-mature optimization--don't do it. Write your code in the cleanest, most simple, most clear way to understand that is possible. Then if there are problems use the profiler tools to find the real performance issues and fix them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd suggest to create a category on NSString with a method that converts it to NSAttributedString and then use that helper method across your project.

Like this:

```
@interface NSString (AttributedStringCreation)
   - (NSAttributedString *)attributedString;
@end

@implementation NSString (AttributedStringCreation)

- (NSAttributedString *)attributedString {
   return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:self];
}

@end
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer.but still it will allocate the memory.Actually i have 1000string where i want to convert them into attributed string.so i want that i dont have to alloc init everytime.

Comment: I would **not** suggest a category, that is just polluting an Apple foundation class. Just write a new class, the method can be a class method so no extra class extension occurs.

Comment: Bentley convertible, in white, can I have? Today delivered. Be waiting I will. But seriously instantiations occur all the time behind the scenes, they are not a problem. They are the only way to create a class,